# How to install dlib and update gcc on Yocto

Tags: c++11, gcc, yocto, dlib

I'm trying to install dlib on Yocto following the instructions on [this page](http://dlib.net/compile.html). However the installation fails at the last command, with the message "error: 'exception-ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a type".

I suspect this is because of C++11 not being properly supported by the gcc version 4.8.2 installed on my machine, based on the very few reports of this happening.

However trying to update gcc to a higher version like 4.9.2 or 5.4.0 also failed because apparently gcc isn't directly compatible with Yocto. Attempting to run make resulted in failure complaining about unknown OS. Therefore I may also need to know how I can update the gcc installed on my Yocto machine as well.

If anyone knows of a good workaround I'd be very glad to know it.

Comment: You can download the `Visual Studio 2015 community edition` and install Visual C++. Visual Studio 2015 supports ISO C++ 14 standard. Another plus point is you can use more than 2 gb of RAM as all programs will be builded using x64 using this command: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..`

Comment: Can't you use a recent gcc (>6) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of gcc version. In yocto you have to specify mcpu flag along with your cxx flags if you are compiling a program with c++11 features.

If you are compiling dlib with python bindings you have to set cxx flags(-mcpu=cortex-a15) in the CMakeList.txt.

I have created a recipe for dlib-19.7 on yocto-1.6 with some patches for boost and if you want i can help you with cross compilation